# Как сделать такой эффект? (линия из точки 1 в точку 2)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать эффект, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку рисовалась линия по указанной траектории из точки 1 в точку 2?

Comment: думаю, вам [сюда](https://habrahabr.ru/post/207908/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы делал на SVG, линию вроде как можно сделать через path, а для кружков с цифрами использовать marker